# SQLBoiler select from another table in `AndIn`

Tags: go, orm, sqlboiler

I am trying to follow the examples in sqlboiler (https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler). But, I can't find a way to add another table in `AndIn` clause, since any `Where` leads to return two values.

```
users, err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
  AndIn("c.kind in ?", "visa", "mastercard"),
).All(ctx, db)
```

In this example, if, we could get a filter a way to fetch values from another table, it'd be equivalent to SQL.

One way to get this done is to obtain the values separately and then feed it in as a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: These sorts of problems are one of the main reasons not to use an ORM. ORMs are ostensibly designed to make life easier. When you start banging your head against the wall because it's difficult to make the ORM do the right thing, it's obviously notmaking life easier any more.

Comment: @flimzy - any suggestion to deal with it?

Comment: My personal suggestion is to never use an ORM.

Comment: If not ORM, then?

Comment: Standard SQL. The normal way.

Comment: Yes, but then if the code changes require db migration, then ORMs are convenient. Standard SQL with break a lot of things in production code. Besides, don't really have an option to not use ORM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194673/discussion-between-vikas-goel-and-flimzy).

Comment: If that's your view, then use an ORM. In my view, an ORM is never convieneint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arbitrary SQL in `Where`.

```golang
users, err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
  Where("c.kind IN (select kind from your_other_table)"),
).All(ctx, db)
```

`WhereIn`, `AndIn` are just handy functions to autogenerate a list of a variable amount of placeholders. `WhereIn("x in ?", "a", "b")` is the same as `Where("x in (?, ?)", "a", "b")`. If you don't need that, just use regular `Where`.